# What is the difference between using a Process and Console Application?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

What would be the difference between running a Symfony console command programatically using:

1-

```
$command = $this->console.'swiftmailer:spool:send > output.log 2> out.log &';
$process = new \Symfony\Component\Process($command);
$process->run();
```

2-

```
$application = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application($kernel);
$application->setAutoExit(false);
        
$payload = ['command' => 'swiftmailer:spool:send'];

$input = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput($payload);

$output = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput();
$application->run($input, $output);
```

I know in terms of handling the results is different but apart from that  is there any other technological difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Process Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) is using the [proc_open function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) under the hood, using your operating system, in order to open file pointers for input/output and the [proc_close](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-close.php) to close a process and return the exit code of the process.

While [The Console Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html) executes your console command without interacting with your operating system, but executes it programmatically within your application. Basically, it calls the `execute` function of your command.

In case you would like to run a Symfony console command, I would suggest to use The Console Component to avoid an operating system overhead, it allows you to pass any parameters you need and get output as well. In case you need to run an external command, the Process Component would be the right choice.